# How to pass variable inside a new instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, variables, swiper.js

I have the following variables. I want to pass `cgggowl_slidesPerView` to the Swiper configuration. How can I do that?

```
var cggowl_jav_info_cont = $scope.find('.cggowl-row').eq(0);
var cgggowl_settings = cggowl_jav_info_cont.data('settings');
var cgggowl_slidesPerView = cgggowl_settings['slidesPerView'];

var mySwiper  = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: cgggowl_slidesPerView,
  spaceBetween: cgggowl_spaceBetween,
});
```

Comment: In isolation the code seems fine. Is there a specific error you receive?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, I realized that the variable that i passed was empty.